# Add excel/csv file to pptx using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am developing a script to generate PPTX automatically using python and I want also to add a file into the presentation.

Comment: Can you add the Python code you have written so far, It sounds like you are trying to create a plugin, can you explain where you are stack.

Comment: I'm trying to find out which package i could use to add a file into pptx.  like using  slide.shapes.add_picture but i need it for csv/excel

Comment: You might not get an answer here because this site is for Programming and solving coding problems or error messages you encounter. I suggest you ask this question on stackexchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/